# How to print a glossary with only the description?

Tags: glossaries

I have a glossary with a number of equations in it and I want to print out **ONLY** the descriptions when \printglossary is called but I'm unable to find how to do this from with within the glossary package User Manual.

My glossaries are in the form:

```
\newglossaryentry{1}
{
    type = Equations,
    name = 1,
    description = 
    {$Relative \ atomic \ mass = \frac{(\% isotope1 \cdot \ Ar\_isotope1) \ + \ (\% isotope2 \cdot \ Ar\_isotope2) \ ...}{100}$
    }
}
```

I need them to have names as I call them using \gls and \glsdesc in another document.

I then print with:

```
\printglossary[type=Equations,title=Equations, toctitle=Equations]
```

Anyone know how to do this printing without the name of the glossary item?

Many thanks.